# how can i make my 2d object crouch in unity and c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i need to make a 2d object shrink on the y axis, or "crouch". however, I've been having a problem trying to get it to work.

at first, i tried to use getcomponent and made a float. i already have a sprint code, so i tried to replicate it but with height. nut, it didn't work, and there was always an error. so i looked something up and copied the code. it had more errors. at one point, there was no errors, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Please tell us what you are actually working on and include the code you are having trouble with. (min reproducible code would be great)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is there any update? Can you provide  more information and minimal code?

Answer (score 0):

have  you tried  moveing the character down when pressing crouch something like get current positon an then -10 on the y axis and changing the hitbox accordinglly and then adding a animation. would be great if you could add an picture. here maybe something like this

````
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
 private bool isCrouching = false;
 private Vector3 originalPosition;
 private Vector3 crouchPosition;

 public float crouchHeight = 0.5f; // You can adjust this value based on your requirements

 // Add your animator reference and other variables as needed

 void Start()
 {
     // Store the original position for reference
     originalPosition = transform.position;

     // Calculate the crouching position based on the crouchHeight
     crouchPosition = originalPosition - new Vector3(0f, crouchHeight, 0f);

     // Add your animator initialization and other setup code here
 }

 void Update()
 {
     // Example: Press "C" to toggle crouch
     if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
     {
         ToggleCrouch();
     }
 }

 void ToggleCrouch()
 {
     // Toggle the crouch state
     isCrouching = !isCrouching;

     // Update player position and hitbox based on crouch state
     if (isCrouching)
     {
         // Move down
         transform.position = crouchPosition;

         // Adjust the hitbox or collider size
         // Example: GetComponent<Collider>().height = crouchHeight;

         // Trigger crouch animation (you need to set up the animator and animation)
         // Example: animator.SetBool("IsCrouching", true);
     }
     else
     {
         // Move back to original position
         transform.position = originalPosition;

         // Adjust the hitbox or collider size back to normal
         // Example: GetComponent<Collider>().height = originalHeight;

         // Trigger stand-up animation
         // Example: animator.SetBool("IsCrouching", false);
     }
 }
}```
````